# What actually does the EntityManger.gettransaction.rollback method do?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions

Does the `rollback` method clear the persistence provider's transaction cache?

Answer (score 0):

A rollback of a transaction means that all work that has been done during the transaction will not be actually persisted and that any temporary changes already made (which typically have limited visibility) will be undone.

There is no such thing as a transaction cache, but there is an L1 entity cache and if configured an L2 cache. If the L2 cache is transactional, then it too will not be updated and any temporal "on hold" changes already propagated to it will be undone.